# What does the meaning of below piece of code (DI)

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, di

I found this code in a di.xml file with the code below. can someone tell me what the piece of code means.

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Downloadable\Pricing\Price\Pool" 
type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wishlist_configured_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Wishlist\Pricing\ConfiguredPrice\Downloadable</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
 </virtualType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a new instance of Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool and pass to argument `prices` in constructor value

```
['wishlist_configured_price' => 'Magento\Wishlist\Pricing\ConfiguredPrice\Downloadable']
```

In the di.xml file, you can use this instance by name alias Magento\Downloadable\Pricing\Price\Pool